# 14.1 does not boot after upgrading from 14.04

Tags: boot, upgrade

I successfully installed 14.04 along with my pre-installed Win8.1.  Ubuntu 14.04 was working fine, but after I restarted to complete the upgraded to 14.10 the screen is just blank/black with a blinking underline.  The boot menu does appear before getting to the blank/black screen, so I am able to boot into Windows8.1

When I tried booting to Ubuntu 14.1 again, the blank/black screen is all I get.  When I press the power button even just one second I see for one second the text "Ubuntu" with the usual progressing dots underneath it, and then the computer shuts down. Do I have to re-install Ubuntu 14.04, or is there a fix to make 14.1 work? If I have to revert back to 14.04, should I use my USB Ubuntu 14.04 install flash drive?

Comment: Do you see the grub menu? How are you able to boot into windows?

Comment: Yes, I see the GRUB, which is how I have been able to scroll down to choose booting into Windows. I guess I should have waited until end of this year before trying 14.1
I tried to boot from the 14.04 Ubuntu USB flash drive, but I only get the same result: the blank screen.  I cannot even re-install 14.04 now

Comment: does it show ubuntu recovery in grub menu?

Comment: No option for Ubuntu recovery. Only the text "GRUB>" appeared as a command line on restart--not a list of choices to boot Windows or Ubuntu.   The GRUB> command  line  gave me a list of possible commands after I pressed "Tab".   I typed "exit", and the EFI (I'm guessing) menu came up allowing me to choose booting either Windows or Ubuntu. Got back into Windows from there at least.  That's how I'll have to boot Windows from now on, which is not a big deal. I'm guessing I would have to delete GRUB first, before trying to re-install Ubuntu 14.04; however, I decided not to attempt that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)